# Can't change background image in body using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to replace an image in body background using jQuery, but no matter what I do, it doesn't work. Code is almost the same as in other questions or tutorials. 
Here's CSS which works:

```
body{
     background-image: url('img/1.jpg');
}
```

But here's jQuery which doesn't:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/2.jpg)');
```

and HTML:

```
 <html lang="pl">
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <Title> Moja firma </Title>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I checked, and jQuery is loaded as well as the file with its code.
I also tried putting quotes in url, but also nothing.

Comment: It may just be an issue with your value being formatted wrong.  try changing it to `'url("img/2.jpg")'` so the value has quotes just like your css rule does.

Comment: I wrote that I tried, and doesn't work.

Comment: Then can you edit your question to make a working example of the issue?  I don't see any other glaring issue with what you have provided.

Comment: In my code is actually nothing, just clear HTML with CSS and JS embedeed, but I can add it

Comment: Check your console for errors loading the image. Is your CSS file in the same directory as the JS file or source file where the style/jQuery are located? this will impact the necessary relative path.

Comment: load script at the end or use `$(function(){     //code     });`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Okay, advice from jasinth premkumar works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working example just wrap your code inside document.ready funtion

```js
$(function(){
  $("body").css('background-image','url(https://recruiterflow.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/stackoverflow.png)');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="pl">
 <head>
 
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <Title> Moja firma </Title>
 </head>
 <body>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work fine when I test the jquery.
So I would suggest moving your `<script src="script.js"></script>` to the bottom of your body tag.

```
<body>
    stuff for page

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Otherwise you should check if the page is ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(img/2.jpg)');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach.

I would do this for each page.

```
<body class="home">
<body class="about">
<body class="contact">
```

Add below css

```
.home header { background-image: url(../assets/img/consulting.png"; }
.about header { background-image: url(../assets/img/consulting2.png"; }
.contact header { background-image: url(../assets/img/consulting3.png"; }
```

On Button click, you can add below js.

```
$(function(){
    $('#aboutlink').click(function(e){
        $('body').removeClass().addClass('about');

        //your other snippets here

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the event that you are triggering the change. The change will not be aplayed if you dont trigger an event. Example:

When the document is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').css('background-image', "url('img/2.jpg')");
})
```

When you hit a button

```
$('button').on("click", function(){
 $('body').css("background-image", "url('img/2.jpg')");
})
```

Here is a working example

https://codepen.io/mercabrand/pen/KeLLrZ

Check also the event that fits your need

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events